# Query in Repository with limit

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I wanted to ask you for help.

I have a `Book` table from which I want to draw two recently added books (there is no add date in the database, I want to sort `idb` - book id).
I want to do this by the appropriately written method name in Repository (i.e. by `Spring Data`)
that is something like that
The `<Book> findAllOrderByIdbDesc();`
I want to limit the results to two and I have a problem with that.
How do you save such a query?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
List<Book> findTop2ByOrderByIdbDesc()
```

For more useful info please follow the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Answer (score 0):

In the BookRepository interface, add:

```
Page<Book> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

To return the last 2 ( or even n ) records sorted by idb in descending order, you should use:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 2, Sort.Direction.DESC, "idb");
Page<Book> books= bookRepository.findAll(pageable)
List<Book> topTwoBookList = books.getContent();
```

Comment: i'm glad  that it helped , to make the answer observable to the whole community, please set the green tick for the working answers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use paging to implement your scenario. Your repository interface would have to extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` for paging support (`JpaRepository` already extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`).

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> { 

    Page<Book> findBooks(Pageable page);

}
```

You can then invoke the method as follows.

```
pageIndex = 0;
pageSize = 2; // you can configure this, if for example you need top 10
bookRepository.findBooks(new PageRequest(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "book.idb");
```

Hope this helps!